# How to pass a big amount of parameters from PHP to a Javascript Function?

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

I'm developing a Joomla module, with several parameters to define how it works. I have buttons in the module area, and buttons have to interact with those parameters. Here is the module PHP code:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');
$AdVisualV2jMODPHP_ver='0.3.0070';
$Station_ID = $params->get('Station_ID');
$Verbose = $params->get('Verbose');
$Bk_ColorODD = $params->get('Bk_ColorODD');
$Bk_ColorEVEN = $params->get('Bk_ColorEVEN');
$Ink_ColorODD = $params->get('Ink_ColorODD');
$Ink_ColorEVEN = $params->get('Ink_ColorEVEN');
$PicCol_Title = $params->get('PicCol_Title');
$TxtCol_Title = $params->get('TxtCol_Title');
$EvPic_Heightpx = $params->get('EvPic_Heightpx');
$EvPic_Widhtpx = $params->get('EvPic_Widhtpx');
$CatPic_Heightpx = $params->get('CatPic_Heightpx');
$CatPic_Widhtpx = $params->get('CatPic_Widhtpx');
$Pic_Hspanpx = $params->get('Pic_Hspanpx');
$Pic_Vspanpx = $params->get('Pic_Vspanpx');
$TitleSw = $params->get('TitleSw');
$MenuPos = $params->get('MenuPos');
$Paging = $params->get('Paging');
$Sort_Field = $params->get('Sort_Field');
$Sort_Order = $params->get('Sort_Order');
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "xxxx";
$db_database = "xxxxx";
$db_password = "xxxxx";
$db_tabconfig = "xxxxxxx";
$db_tabpreroll = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

echo 'AVVIAMO LA PROCEDURA 0.0.090 - '.$Station_ID.'<br><br>';
echo '<div id="TabellaEventi"></div>';
echo '<INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Avanti" ONCLICK="avanti()"> ';
echo '<INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Indietro" ONCLICK="indietro()"> ';
echo '<br>';
?>
```

When the user will click on the "Avanti" or "Indietro" buttons i call the JAVASCRIPT functions avanti() and indietro(), and those two functions will work with ALL the parameters above. How can I do to transfer this huge amount of variables?

AND!!! The two Javascript functions will have to call OTHER PHP files to interact with a MySql database, and again i will need more or less ALL the variables in the other file.

Internet programming is such a mess sometime...

Comment: AJAX, and php javascript variable definition

Comment: Use an an Array and AJAX

Comment: why are you defining the database details in this file?

Comment: because i will use other external PHP files to display some data, accessing to a database, and i don't want to repeat those informations in a lot of other places - that's my idea, other better suggestion(s)? TY

Comment: Answer a few questions, and maybe I can get you a better answer. 1) What version of Joomla? 2) Where are the JS functions posting to? 3) Would you mind sharing the module code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax might not needed. Put all your variable in a big array of data

```
$data['Station_ID'] = $params->get('Station_ID');
$data['Verbose'] = $params->get('Verbose');
...

$data = json_encode($data);
$data = htmlentities($data);
...
echo '<INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Avanti" ONCLICK="avanti(' . $data . ')"> ';
```

Now avanti contains an JSON object as 1st parameter

Edit: because the JSON string might contain `"` and `<` you must call `htmlentities` to protect your string

Comment: sounds interesting, but can you please help me a little in decoding this array once i will be in JS? thank you very much

Comment: There is no decoding needed. It's an JSON object already. If you want to extract the information, do json.Station_ID for example. Use console.log(json) to debug it.. (json is the parameter of avanti(json))

Comment: It works, good suggestion! But now i have the problem to call another PHP file passing again all the parameters :-(

Comment: @RobertoAlfieri If the two files is not connected to each other (no include() after getting $data), then you should use session. PS: I don't know what $param is but if you can transfer $param and stored in session, you can use it anywhere to get your value

Answer (score 1):

you can use JSON + jQuery.

Q1:
create a global JS varible first.

```
var params = {"Station_ID":"","":"",......}
```

Q2:
use ajax call with jQuery.

```
var queryURL = 'your php file';
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:queryURL,
    data: params// params in Q1 
}).done(function(jsonObj){ 
        dosomething();
});
```